# how to drag a desktop application icon onto a webpage and display this icon on the webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have been searching for this drag and display on a webpage for quite a while.
All the tutorials or information which I have found only talk about how to do the drag and drop, but it doesn't meet my requirement.

I want to drag an icon from my desktop on to my local website(running on my PC), and then the icon should be displayed on the webpage.

Please shed me light on this and any your thought is valuable.

I tried to look into the relevant events, but I cannot find which event can provide me the names of files and how to display icons on the webpage(ASP.NET).

Thank you

Comment: This goes directly against the security cordon that protects your PC from malicious websites. So it's a matter of 'not allowed'.

Comment: Icon?.. You mean a shortcut? Then I do not think it can be done, since the shortcut displays the icon from the corresponding `.exe` file. If you want to drag the application itself and display its icon, the you should upload it to your server, take its icon using server code and display it on the webpage.

Comment: @HenkHolterman hi,thx for ur reply. What if the website is a localhost website, in which I can assign all permissions to this website?

Comment: @pckill hi，thx for ur reply. yes a shortcut but I'd like to display its icon as well. The website is running on local machine(I made the website, so it's trustworthy) so is it to achieve my thought?

Comment: Nope, you have to upload the `.exe` file to grab its icon, can't do that with a shortcut.